# Is it possible to upsert a subcollection entity for a parent document that does not yet exist?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

We are building an auth system that stores a subcollection of Sessions under a User document, which in turn lives under a User collection.

Example pseudocode:

```
.set("users/{USER_ID}/sessions/{SESSION_ID}", sessionData)
```

Is it possible to upsert a new session *without* having created the parent User document (with `USER_ID`) in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a new document at a nested path even if the parent documents don't exist.

For mobile and web apps, you can also use security rules to make sure that the parent `USER_ID` exists before allowing a new session document.